# slideup animation in angular and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui

i need to create a menu in angular and javascript . i need this menu show and hide with button .

i write code and i show it here : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-endnvn)

i need to when click button , the `start-item` slideup with animation and when i click that button again `start-item` slidedown with animation .

how can i do this with jquery ???

```
showHideMenu(is: boolean) {
var elem = document.querySelector('.start-Itms');
if (this.isOpen) {
  console.log(this.isOpen)
  elem.classList.remove('hidden');
  elem.classList.add('visible');
  this.isOpen = false;
} else {
  console.log(this.isOpen)
  elem.classList.remove('visible');
  elem.classList.add('hidden');
  this.isOpen = true;
}
```

}

HTML :

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0 content">
<div class="startMenu p-0 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
    <div class="start p-0" (click)="showHideMenu(isOpen)">
        <img src="../../../assets/img/Icon/windows-10-solo-logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-32 col-sm-32 col-lg-32 col-xl-32">
        <input>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="start-Itms" id="start-Itms">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use jQuery if you can achieve this behavior via CSS? [See Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfx7kk)

The only changes I did was from these rules:

```
.start-Itms {
    ...
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

to these:

```
.start-Itms {
    ...
    transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}

.visible {
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

PS - This way is more performant and smoother since I'm not changing the height (unlike jQuery) and as a result, the browser doesn't recalculate the layout.

PS 2 - Take a look at this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfx7kk). I've changed the toggling logic. This is more Angular-y way to do things in Angular. Plus, it's much less code.